# GWT: Singleton Dashboard using UiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I want to create a Dashboard which is Singleton. But unable to sort out where to place **initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this))** .

Also, createAndBindUi(this) needs **this** instance of the class. How to proceed? I am new to GWT.

```
public class UserDashboard extends Composite{

interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, UserDashboard> {}
private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);



 private static UserDashboard userDash= new UserDashboard();   //singleton Dashboard;


private UserDashboard(){}

public static UserDashboard getDashInstance(){

  //**initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this))**;
    return userDash;
}
```

Comment: In the constructor, like every other widget. Whether it's a singleton or not is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: I would suggest to use GIN following its documentation

https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial + search for GIN + uibinder for more example.

Answer (score 0):

Create a View Factory and return the view from there.